# Will my laptop work in the U.S

Tags: power-supply, power

I bought a PlayStation 3 from the us and when I moved it back to Egypt I had to use a stabilizer for it to work, do I have to do something similar for my laptop which I bought from Egypt (the normal voltage is 240v) for it to work in the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having a stabilizer adapter will be safer. ( Those like travelling adapters).  Due to different currents, it may damage the components if u do not use the adapter.

Comment: Maybe not, most of the computer chargers support both 110 & 240, you can take a look at your charger for the supported voltage, if your country voltage is mentioned you can use it safely

Comment: Yeah it has 100~240 written on it, is it safe to use?

Comment: Yes Furious. You only need a basic adaptor so that the plug will fit into the wall outlet, and that's all.